# Unity, get youtube url through a web view and play the video in unity

Tags: android, ios, webview, youtube, unity-game-engine

I need a webview in unity where I can search for youtube videos. If I have found the right video I need to copy the URL. In Unity I need to find a way to play that video through my Easy Movie Texture plugin, so I need to play the video on a plane.

First of all, I do not know how a webview can communicate with unity, so that I can get the current URL. For example I would use Prime31 for my webview. Second of all, I have no idea how I can get the streaming URL / .mp4 of a youtube video.

Maybe some has an idea how to accomplish this?

I work with the latest Unity 5.3

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this :
https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/29704

Only play youtube videos on mobile.

Comment: Instead of posting links as answer add some text to explanation how this answer help to OP in fixing current issue.Thanks

Comment: This plugin works well with Easy Movie Texture, you can add the youtube url and play the result video in Easy Movie texture,

Comment: Does this stream videos in 360?